# SSL on frontend and backend server with IIS and XAMPP Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, iis, server

I have a Window Server 2019.
The server has install XAMPP and its Apache is listening on 80 & 443. (Apache has other old projects) (old project url: oldproject1.domain.com)
The server has install IIS and its hosting a Frontend at 1004 and Backend at 1003. (New Project)

I can now use XAMPP redirect to IIS by typing newproject.domain.com
I install a SSL Cer to the Front via Apache.
So i can visit frontend by https://newproject.domain.com
But error appears on "Mix Content Error", it means my backend is http and my frontend is https which is blocked.

So my question is:

1. Is it posible to have a SSL for domain.com and all XYZ.domain.com can use this SSL?
2. If I get SSL for my backend, can SSL work on IP address but not a domain
3. Is any method to let my frontend (with SSL) connect my backend (No SSL) without any errors?

Comment: I found there are some SSL for a whole Domain *.domain.com, but it seem so expensive, 800USD per one per year. It ok to use two different SSL and install both on Apache, and let Apache (https) redirect to IIS which the IIS is still hosting as http. Remember to change frontend API baseUrl.

Comment: And third party app can connect this backend by `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/` (ip) or `https://newproject.domain.com`. But if using web-app, and connect the http one, u may still face the same error  "Mixed Content".

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.